# Can we automate installation of a software and also automate configuration by using pywinauto?

Tags: pywinauto

I'm new to silent installation and would like to know that can we install and configure a software like username password or port number by just one click by writing a script in python using pywinauto.

Answer (score 0):

The question has not enough details. So the answer would be "yes, it's possible". But this will produce a lot of disrespect on StackOverflow since you didn't show your efforts and wasting time of experts hiding the details: steps to reproduce, examples of code, links to app samples or another technical things. In this case experts can't be sure you'll accept correct answer so the motivation to reply becomes lower by many reasons.

You also may face with some standard pitfalls with GUI automation that can be workarounded, but again it's hard to predict without the details. If it's not for GUI testing (just for automation, right?), I'd recommend the following:

1. Figure out how to perform installation by command line. Many `setup.exe` installers have help option `/?` and silent installation option like `/s` (it depends on the installer). If it's `.msi` installer, use `msiexec` command (learn its help also) to proceed with one command installation.
2. Make sure you have active desktop (i.e. machine is not locked, RDP window is not minimized and not disconnected) because it's important for GUI automation: particularly for pywinauto we have methods `.type_keys(...)` and `.click_input()` that require active desktop. Some methods don't require active desktop though.
3. Then prepare pywinauto script to login in your GUI app. This script can be called from main batch script.